# .find("tagname") empty result (occasionally works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I need help with some JavaScript. I have a page that does only display correctly in Chrome. That is due to me only developing for Chrome because it is just very easy to use and forgives a lot of mistakes.

I use JQuery to get an XML object $xmlresponse. It has a structure a little something like this:

```
<evelope:specificbody> 
<firstlevel:multimediaobjects>
<secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant>
TextNode that I need
</secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant>
<secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant>
Another TextNode
</secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant>
</firstlevel:multimediaobjects>
</evelope:specificbody>
```

`$($xmlresponse).find("*")` delivers all the nodes correctly. But as soon as I want to address the nodes with jQuery I do not get any results. Even though my page displays in Chrome I can not reproduce

```
$($xmlresponse).find("thisIsWhatIWant")
results in []
```

to deliver me all nodes.

Help is appreciated

Comment: Any difference if you use `$('thisIsWhatIWant', $xmlresponse)`?

Comment: This is a bit of an aside, but if you're learning, the last thing you want is something that is "very easy to use and forgives a lot of mistakes". You'll learn bad habits, and it's a lot harder to unlearn them then to learn good form in the first-place.

Comment: @landons This is actually not working. It delivers an empty response, too.

Comment: I solved another problem that I mixed up with this one that might be interesting for others who stumble upon this post: Be aware, that ajax response is a #document. I accessed it (probably in a bad habit) via `$(xmlresponse[0].firstChild)` now the `.find()` works a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to include the namespace:

```
$( $xmlresponse ).find("secondlevel\\:thisIsWhatIWant")
```

`\\` will escape the colon.

But better is to get via `nodeName`

```
$( $xmlresponse ).find( "[nodeName=secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant]" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I do the first one, it works just fine. But I can't get the second one to work. It gives me a `$($xmlresponse).find('[nodename=secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant]')
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [nodename=secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant]"`

Comment: `nodeName` should be camelCase

Comment: Don't you need to put `"secondlevel:thisIsWhatIWant"` in quotes?

Comment: Neither one works for me. But now I am completely lost: When I use a similar XML-structure:`<h-tm:li><bo:die>
<Gi-mme:Text>
Hey there!
</Gi-mme:Text>\
<Gimme:Text>\
I am Text
</Gimme:Text>
</bo:die>
</h-tm:li>` 
This works perfectly with: $( $xmlresponse ).find("gi-mme\\:text")
@landons: The second quotes deliver an empty result, too.